# Bootstrapping cell type identifications (scRNA-seq)

Tags: scrnaseq, statistics

I have scRNA-seq data held in a `SEURAT` object, and cell-types were identified with `SingleR` (essentially a vector of strings - Monocytes, Granulocytes etc.). I have two conditions - treated and untreated. I want to know if the difference in the relative frequency (%) of a given cell type between the conditions is significant. For this, I thought to perform bootstrapping, to obtain frequencies for many different 'simulated' datasets - and then perform a statistical test. However, I cannot understand how best to do this. Should I subsample the scRNA-seq data, with replacement and calculate the frequencies each time? Can somebody provide a step by step workflow on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use permutation:

i) Get the difference that you are interested in, i.e. number/proportion of monocytes in one group vs the other.

ii) Get the relevant columns (condition, cell label, ...) from the `@meta.data` slot of your seurat objects and `rbind()`.

iii) Shuffle the cell labels randomly and split the data frame into two (per condition).

iv) Compare the difference between the cell counts/proportions of interest from the two permuted data frames and save this value.

iv) Repeat iii and iv for 100s of times and calculate how many times have you observed a difference at least as extreme as your real observation (i). Once divided by the number of trials, this would give you a p-value stating how likely it is that you get the observed value.

I have to add that batch effects are severe in scRNA-seq and hence a linear model where you might be able to account for batches could be more helpful.